# Running a gradle project in Intellij IDEA in a WSL2 instance

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to run a gradle project in IntelliJ IDEA. The project is cloned in WSL2 ubuntu instance. I have downloaded the JDK through the IDE in WSL, given the correct gradle home and set the JVM in the settings, and the project SDK is also set to the same.

But the issue happens when it builds, it tries to get the JDK path from the windows directory. My gradle home directory is set to:
`/home/username/.gradle/jdks/temurin-8-amd64-linux/jdk8u382-b05/bin`

But the build fails with the following message:

`F:\home\username\.gradle\jdks\temurin-8-amd64-linux\jdk8u382-b05\bin\jdks\temurin-8-amd64-linux\jdk8u382-b05 doesn't exist`

(F drive is where intellij IDEA is installed)

There is the option of running the project using **Remote development** options but I am just wondering if there is a way to fix the pathing where the IDE is insalled in windows and the project is in WSL2 instance. Because other different environments work fine i.e. Node, Golang, and Rust projects work as expected as the binaries are installed in the WSL instance.

Here is also a screenshot of my gradle settings if it helps at all:
[image]

Comment: The places I would start are... does just typing `java` and seeing if it finds it.  If that works,  type `which java` to find where it's located.  From powershell, you can type `Get-Command java` to likewise find it.  Inspect the paths, especially in the WSL.  Also, check the value of `JAVA_HOME` env var.

Comment: Can you post the full build output, so we can better understand when/why it refers to the Windows FS? Does changing "Gradle user home" to default have any effect on the issue?